# extract strings between last two slashes using regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract the string between last two string using a regular expression. I cannot seem to be able to come up with the right expression, if someone could help me that would be great.

Say the string is: aa/bbbb/ccccc/eeee/fffff.jpg, I want to extract out "eeee".

Thank you.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aV9lK1/1
??
Capturing a named group can help to name your required data.

Comment: Pretty decent @shafaq -- but definitely _do not_ assume a 3-character extension — no extension is legal, `.html` and `.properties` are legal. How about `/.*\/([^/]*)\/[^/]*/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only care about the *last* set of slashes, you start by matching anything
`.*`
then you want a literal slash
`\/` (escaped since the slash would terminate the js regex)
now you want anything up to the next slash, which implies *not a slash* and _there must be something (one-or-more) and we'll put that in a capturing group so you can extract it.
`([^/]+)`
and followed by another literal slash
`\/`
then anything else (the file name?) that, again, does not include slashes
`[^/]+`

Putting that all together gives you the regex
`/.*\/([^/]+)\/[^/]+/`
and
`"aa/bbbb/ccccc/eeee/fffff.jpg".match(/.*\/([^/]+)\/[^/]+/);`
produces
`["aa/bbbb/ccccc/eeee/fffff.jpg", "eeee"]`
... the *eeee* is captured.

Answer (score 4):

I know you said you wanted to use a regex but for those looking for a solution but don't require it to be a regex, you could do this simply by splitting the string:

```
 var originalString = 'aa/bbbb/ccccc/eeee/fffff.jpg';

 //convert to array
 var parts = originalString.split('/');

 //find the second to last item
 var lastPartOfPath = '';

 //make sure there are more than one part
 if (parts.length > 1) {
      lastPartOfPath = parts[parts.length-2];
 }
```